# Angular Directive and Childrens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I wan't to make a Directive for Angular 1.x. I'm thinking in something like this:

```
<myDirective>
     <div class="title">Header</div>
     <div class="content>Content here</div>
</myDirective>
```

So my question if it's posible access to "title" and "content" class of the html and change, for example, the background color for "title" element..

Anyone can help me?

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking.  Are you asking how to make your directive have access to those elements?

Comment: why wouldnt you be able to do this via css? and yes btw, you can access them through the directive itself

Comment: I'm thinking in a directive beacuse will be much more elements with class "title" and "content"...

Comment: I agree that it is unclear what you are asking-- from the language used it seems like javascript/angular don't even fit into the equation-- its a simple html/css scenario...

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it by normal css as you would do for any other html content.
here is a working link to see how it works https://plnkr.co/edit/WaqTKb4IhjlWZsE5Q7Cb?p=preview

so if your directive was :

```
<my-directive>
 <div class="title">Header</div>
 <div class="content>Content here</div>
</my-directive>
```

you could access the elements like so (these styles go where you're defining styles for the rest of the normal html)

```
my-directive > .title
{
background-color:red;
}

my-directive > .content
{
background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-class` to do it. Declare your CSS classes that will alternate in the directive, and use a condition in `ng-class` that will decide which will be active.

Some examples of how to use it:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'text-success': awesome, 'text-large': giant }">

<div ng-class="$variableToEvaluate ? 'class-if-true' : 'class-if-false'">
```

Here is the docs about it:

[ng-class docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

You can look into this site for more details on how to use `ng-class`:

[The many ways to use ng-class](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

Good luck!